# problemas con hacer consultas sql en nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

El id lo paso por parametro a mi función de consulta, pero da error al ejecutar la consulta

este es mi codigo:

```
objBD.query('SELECT u.ID_U, u.nombre, l.ID_L,letra, t.ID_T,tiempo from USUARIO u INNER JOIN LETRA l ON u.ID_U = l.ID_U INNER JOIN TIEMPOS t ON l.ID_L=t.ID_L where u.ID_U='+result.insertId', function(err, rows, fields) {
        console.log(rows);
```

result.insertId   es el id, mi pregunta es como hacer una consulta con un parametro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi así:

```
objBD.query('SELECT u.ID_U, u.nombre, l.ID_L,letra, t.ID_T,tiempo from USUARIO u INNER JOIN LETRA l ON u.ID_U = l.ID_U INNER JOIN TIEMPOS t ON l.ID_L=t.ID_L where u.ID_U=?',[result.insertId], function(err, rows, fields) {
        console.log(rows);
        //

});
```

Poniéndolo entre corchetes los parámetros requeridos, se los separa entre comas cada parámetro requerido para realizar la consulta.